# How to align legends in bottom center

Tags: charts, flutter

I'm using [google charts for flutter](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html) and trying to align legends in the bottom middle.

I've tried using `outsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea` but its still aligned left. Is there an option to align legends in the center?

this is what i have

```
charts.NumericComboChart(
        data,
        animate: true,
        // hide Axis
        primaryMeasureAxis: noneAxisRenderer,
        // hide Axis
        secondaryMeasureAxis: noneAxisRenderer,
        // hide Axis
        domainAxis: noneAxisRenderer,
        // Configure the default renderer as a line renderer. This will be used
        // for any series that does not define a rendererIdKey.
        defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(),
        // Custom renderer configuration for the point series.
        behaviors: [
          charts.SeriesLegend(
            position: charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
            cellPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
            outsideJustification: charts.OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea,
          ),
        ],
      );
```

which results in this: 
[image]